# jquery to html (by text) to server (by $_POST)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

In JS/Jquery i have a button, and every time button is clicked a var is incremented. Then i send that variable to html, like this:

```
//....
var x++;
//....
$('#Score').text(x);
```

No problem here.
Then, in html i have a form like this (that activates when i press "finish" image):

```
<form name="form_1" method="post" action="form_1_submit.php">
<input name="Score" id="Score" style="display:none;"></div>
<input src="../finish.png" id="finish_btn" type="image">
</form>
```

I also have a submit file:

```
//...
$r1 = $_POST['Score'];
//...
$insert = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO challenge_log (userID, challengeID, tries, question, answer) VALUES ('$id','$ch','$try','$question','$r1')");
$insert->execute();
```

The problem is that i cant get $r1. 
When i check the database i have all values but r1...
Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Try $('#Score').val(x);

Comment: Try checking the browser console to see if $r1 is throwing an error. You could also try `console.log($r1)` to see if it is getting a value.

Comment: In addition to Boris' comment, try adding a type, i.e.: `type="text"` or hidden (<edit) to your `<input name="Score" id="Score" style="display:none;">` - That could be a contributing factor.

Comment: use hidden field <input name="Score" id="Score" type="hidden">

Comment: @MuhammadAli *Ah*, yes. I think that's what the OP should be using; most likely, since he/she is using `display:none`, that could work.

Answer (score 0):

Make the "score" input type="hidden", instead of doing a display:none. Also, I hope you're sanitizing your inputs prior to database insertion!